# How do I animate my sprite correctly?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a 2D platformer on Pygame. While I have successfully animated my enemy sprite when facing left, I struggle to do the same when I flip the image to make him face right. I suspect it's because I've used `self.currentImage = 4` underneath `self.x += self.speed`, so it keeps looping and skipping through the other images I blitted. Basically, the image looks like it's just skipping whereas from `selfcurrentimage` 1 to `self.currentimage` 3, the animation is working smoothly.

```
class Enemy:
def __init__(self,x,y):

    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = 55
    self.height = 51
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height)
    self.speed=1
    self.s0 = pygame.image.load("s0.png")
    self.s1 = pygame.image.load("s1.png")
    self.s2 = pygame.image.load("s2.png")
    self.s3 = pygame.image.load("s3.png")
    self.attack = pygame.image.load("attack.png")
    self.rotateds0 = pygame.transform.flip(self.s0 ,True, False)
    self.rotateds1 = pygame.transform.flip(self.s1 ,True, False)
    self.rotateds2 = pygame.transform.flip(self.s2 ,True, False)
    self.rotateds3 = pygame.transform.flip(self.s3 ,True, False)

    self.rotate = False
    collision2 = False
    self.TimeTarget = 10
    self.TimeNum = 0
    self.currentImage = 0

def move(self,player):
    if player.x > 100:
        if self.x > player.x:
            self.x -= self.speed
        elif self.x < player.x:
            self.x += self.speed
            self.currentImage = 4

def update(self,CollisionDetect,player):
    self.TimeNum+=1
    if self.TimeNum == self.TimeTarget:
        if self.currentImage == 0:
            self.currentImage = 1
        elif self.currentImage == 1:
            self.currentImage = 2
        elif self.currentImage == 2:
            self.currentImage = 3
        elif self.currentImage == 3:
            self.currentImage = 0
        elif self.currentImage == 4:
            self.currentImage = 5
        elif self.currentImage == 5:
            self.currentImage = 6
        elif self.currentImage == 6:
            self.currentImage = 7
        elif self.currentImage == 7:
            self.currentImage = 4

        self.TimeNum = 0

    if self.currentImage == 0:
        screen.blit(self.s0, (self.x,self.y))
    elif self.currentImage == 1:
        screen.blit(self.s1, (self.x,self.y))
    elif self.currentImage == 2:
        screen.blit(self.s2, (self.x,self.y))
    elif self.currentImage == 3:
        screen.blit(self.s3, (self.x,self.y))
    elif self.currentImage == 4:
        screen.blit(self.rotateds0, (self.x,self.y))
    elif self.currentImage == 5:
        screen.blit(self.rotateds1, (self.x,self.y))
    elif self.currentImage == 6:
        screen.blit(self.rotateds2, (self.x,self.y))
    elif self.currentImage == 7:
        screen.blit(self.rotateds3, (self.x,self.y))

    collision2 = CollisionDetect(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height,player.x,player.y,player.width,player.height)
```

Comment: btw: user list with images then you will have one `blit(self.images[self.currentImage], ... )`

Comment: you can't set `self.currentImage = 4` in every move. It must be done only if `self.x < player.x and self.previous_x > player.previous_x`. Or maybe you have to do only once in `__init__` - `if self.x > player.x: self.currentImage = 0 ; else: self.currentImage = 4`

Answer (score 1):

You set `self.currentImage = 4` in every move so it can't change to 5, 6 or 7. You have to do it only if in current move you have `self.x < player.x` but in previous move you had `self.x > player.x` (enemy changed direction). You can use `self.currentImage` to recognize that situation - if in previous move you had `self.x > player.x` then `self.currentImage` still is `< 4`

```
def move(self,player):

    if player.x > 100:

        if self.x > player.x:
            self.x -= self.speed
            # enemy changed direction
            if self.currentImage > 3:
                self.currentImage = 0

        elif self.x < player.x:
            self.x += self.speed
            # enemy changed direction
            if self.currentImage < 4:
                self.currentImage = 4
```

Comment: Thanks alot it makes sense and helped alot!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't force the frame number in `move()`. Instead of that, use a separate variable that will select from normal or flipped images, and set a value for that in `move()`. Maybe you intended `self.rotate` for exactly this purpose.

That will also simplify that state machine for currentImage to a simple addition and wrap-around.